# Imagick delegates installation on WAMP

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp, imagick

I would like to know how to download the correct Imagemagick decode delegates from http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/, as well what to do with them afterwards.

I'm using:

- Imagick 3.4.3RC1, 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64 2016-03-27
- PHP 5.6.25
- WAMP 3.0.0.25 on Windows 7

I've been looking on Imagick and Stackoverflow threads, but the ones I found were mostly concerning errors with the delegates *after* they had them, and none of them used WAMP. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Also, phpinfo() says under *imagick*: **ImageMagick number of supported formats: 0**

Comment: I am surprised that an install of Imagick does not come with an install of ImageMagick with delegates. Can you not just install a Windows binary version of ImageMagick, which is compatible with your version of Imagick, so that it comes with all the delegates. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: I ran into issues with getting the latest version of Imagick to play nice with my system. Would I be able to theoretically copy the delegates from the newest binary and paste them into the right folder in my installation?

Comment: Please download imagick + ImageMagick from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/ "no supported formats" happens when you've download libraries from different places.

Comment: Why are you using a RC (Release Candidiate) version of Imagick. And RC1? When there is a RC2/RC3/RC4 as well. Use the actual release 3.4.3 Release candidates are basically Beta+ versions

Comment: Also did you download the Thread Safe version (TS) version. The NTS version wont work with WAMPServer

Comment: Also what is WAMPServer 3.0.0.25?? Do you mean WAMPServer 3 or 2.5?

Comment: Is your WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit

Comment: While this link is for php7 it's still relevant. Give it a good read and you should find your solution, https://herbmiller.me/2016/06/16/installing-imagick-php-7/

Comment: @mdo123 Except for the current _Catch 22_ situation we are all currently in with the `imagick` not yet being available for running with `ImageMagick 7` as `imagick` has not yet been compiled against `ImageMagick 7` and that is the only version of `ImageMagick` available for download on their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past this has worked by installing `ImageMagick` and then downloading a compatible `imagick` PHP extension.

But currently there seems to be a temporary "Catch 22" situation with `ImageMagick` and `imagick`.

`imagick` versions need to be compiled against a specific version of `ImageMagick` and currently that has not been done for `imagick` against the new `ImageMagick 7` although I am informed by @danack that `imagick` is ready to be compiled but nobody has done so yet, or at least they have not shared the binary.

Unfortunately `ImageMagick` do not retain older versions of their install i.e. `ImageMagick 6.?` so if you dont already have a version of the installer the only availaible one is `ImageMagick 7`

***The Catch 22***

Therefore the only versions of `imagick` available will only work with `ImageMagick 6` and you cannot download `ImageMagick 6` as the `ImageMagick` people do not retain old version of their installer.

***The work around***

However, if you only want ImageMagick to work within a PHP/Apache environment this proceedure works.

The versions of the following must match your WAMPServer, so if you installed WAMPServer 32bit use the 32bit versions of ImageMagick and Imagick, if you use WAMPServer 64bit, use the 64bit versions of ImageMagick and Imagick.
The VC14 versions should work with WAMPServers Apache 2.4.x versions

1. Download `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x86.zip` (32bit)
   or       `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` (64bit)
   from `http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/` depending upon which WAMPServer version you are using i.e. 32bit or 64bit
2. Download `php_imagick-3.4.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip` (32bit)
   or       `php_imagick-3.4.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip` (64bit)
   from `http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3/` depending upon which WAMPServer version you are using i.e. 32bit or 64bit
3. Create a folder to hold ImageMagick, I used `wamp\imagemagick`
4. Unzip whichever of the ImageMagick's you downloaded i.e.
   `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x86.zip` or `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` into the `wamp\imagemagick` folder
5. Unzip whichever of the imagick version you downloaded `php_imagick-3.4.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip` (32bit) or `php_imagick-3.4.3-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip` (64bit) into a temp folder and copy the `php_imagick.dll` from the temp folder to your `wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext` folder
6. Edit your 'php.ini`file to add the extension. Use the wampmanager menus so you edit the correct file
   (left click) wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
   Add the line`extension=php_imagick.dll`into the section of`php.ini`that contains the other`extension` parameters.
7. Add the folder to your windows PATH using
   Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Setting
       Select the Advanced Tab
       Click the Environment Variables Button
       Add `C:\wamp\imagick;` to the PATH variable in the `System Variables` section
   [I dont like adding anything to the PATH for WAMPServer, but I cannot think of a better solution for now and as this way will work for multiple versions of PHP it is not actually so bad]

Start WAMPServer, or restart Apache. It may be necessary to reboot windows, it was for me, but maybe that was because I tried a number of things before I got to this solution.

Check with `phpinfo()` you should see
[image]

Comment: "it appears that the imagick PHP extension is not yet compatible with the new ImageMagick" - it is. It just needs someone who cares about windows to compile it and possible share that binary with others.

Comment: @Danack Thanks for the info. So basically until it is compiled, it is not compatible right?

Comment: @Danack I have changed my description of the current situation. It was not my intent to be unpleasant to the maintainers of `imagick` as I know you are one or maybe the only one of those.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly One thing though, if phpinfo() says my compiler is VC11, should I download  `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` or `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc11-x64.zip`? Will it make any difference? (I have WAMP64)

Comment: Then you download the `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc11-x64.zip`